# How to use call a plugin inside my view in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a portion of code/view that I am going to use in many places on my cakephp application, it's a filter that I want to add to certain listings of some table.

I don't know if I have to use a view element and embed some php code in it, or create a plugin that I will call each time I need this filter.

I tried both ways but I have some difficulties.

Using Element view :

```
<?php 
    Controller::loadModel('City');
    $cities = $this->City->find('all');
?>
<select name="city" id="city" class="input-medium">
    <option value="">City ...</option>
    <?php foreach ($cities as $city): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $city['City']['id']; ?>"><?php echo $city['City']['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($city); ?>
</select>
```

Using this results on the following error :

```
Missing Helper
Error: usesHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class usesHelper below in file: app\View\Helper\usesHelper.php
```

Using a plugin :

I did follow the tutorial on the official site but I have no idea how to call the the plugin's view (the filter) into my view.

Please Help !

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot have followed the tutorials. What you are doing here is nowhere close to whats described there. You never use the controller this way, and you never use models in the view layer.

Comment: What @mark said. In the first two lines you're trying to invoke controller functionality inside a view. That will (and does) brake everything and even if you tried something that would work then it would break the MVC paradigm and all what makes CakePhp an MVC framework. Start reading about view elements and perhaps also `Controller::requestAction()` from the cookbook to accomplish what you seem to be trying.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here, what tutorial have you followed :|? `Error: usesHelper could not be found.` <- and the code which is responsible for the reported error (somewhere in a view file there is `$this->uses->...`) isn't in the question. FWIW the element can be replaced with basically this much code: `echo $this->Form->select('city', array('class' => 'input-medium', 'id' => 'city', 'empty' => 'City...'))` - it should either contain something very similar to that, or not exist at all. Try asking how to achieve your end objective, rather than your current attempt.

Comment: You’re going against not only CakePHP’s conventions, but the convention of the MVC programming pattern itself. *Never* try and call a controller or model from your views, and *definitely* don’t try and call **both** from your views. In your case, I’d create a view element that you can re-use throughout your application, and request the cities using `$this->requestAction()`.

Comment: @MartinBean careful, `$foo = ClassRegistry::init('SomeModel');` is acceptable in various circumstances.

Comment: @AD7six I’d like to know such a circumstance as like I say, calling a model from a view is against MVC’s principles. Just because it’s possible to do something, doesn’t mean you should.

Comment: @MartinBean instanciating a model in a _cached_ element is common  and acceptable.

Comment: @AD7six How so? What difference does it make if any element is cached or rendered on the fly? A view by no means should be accessing the model layer.